# Using a foreach loop to access threads in a list of threads

Tags: java, loops, foreach, java-threads

I am trying to iterate over threads in a foreach loop, but I get an error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Thread`

The loop is in `private static void waitForThreads(List threads)`

```
import java.util.*;

public class ThreadCreator {

    public static void multiply(int[][] matrix1, int[][] matrix2, int[][] result) {

        List threads = new ArrayList<>();
        int numberOfRows = matrix1.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
            MatrixRow row = new MatrixRow(result, matrix1, matrix2, i);
            Thread thread = new Thread(row);
            thread.start();
            threads.add(thread);
            if (threads.size() % 10 == 0) {
                waitForThreads(threads);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void waitForThreads(List threads) {
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        threads.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: In order for that to work the List must be declared as `List<Thread>`.

Comment: You specify no type argument for `threads`, so it defaults to `Object`.  What would happen if you added an integer to `threads`?  Think about that.  You probably want `List<Thread> threads`.

Comment: Did you apply it in both locations?  You declare it as a local variable in `multiply()` and as a parameter in `waitForThreads()`, so you need to specify the type argument in both locations.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong FYI: There is a fine difference. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2770692/12323248), around the middle.

Comment: @akuzminykh Good point, thanks.  I think I've read that exact post before but I had forgotten the details.  In the OP's specific situation, it amounts to the same behavior, but it's definitely an important difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `waitForThreads` method you haven't specified the generic type of your `List` argument. You should be using:

```
List<Thread>
```

otherwise a `List` is just effectively a `List<Object>`.